# Error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

Today I started working with classes. I created some classes to get my `MainWindow.xmal.cs` a bit smaller. After creating the first classes and debugging, I get the following error message:

> Eine nicht behandelte Ausnahme des Typs "System.StackOverflowException" ist in mscorlib.dll aufgetreten.
>
> Eine nicht behandelte Ausnahme des Typs "System.StackOverflowException" ist in APPLICATION.exe aufgetreten.

```
class Sprachpaket_ENG_Template01
{
    MainWindow MW = new MainWindow();

    public void Template01()
    {
        MW.checkBox_1_Bcc.Content = "Bcc:";
        MW.checkBox_1_Cc.Content = "Cc:";
    }
```

--> This causes the error: **MainWindow MW = new MainWindow();**

Comment: the error is in the //... code

Comment: Best way to cause this would be `public int Foo { get { return Foo; } }`, so maybe look for something like that.

Comment: And where exactly? It's just some more assignments like... MI_04.Header = CHN_MT.MenuitemTitel_04; ... and so on.

Comment: @Exception You expect now someone to actually guess how the line with the error looks like? :| Show the relevant code, and the stack trace. And btw. - try to read it yourself, the error should be evident.

Comment: The code you posted will not cause an exception. There is probably code somewhere in your application that is infinitely recursive.

Comment: I've added another code example.

Comment: It looks like there error is in the `MainWindow()` constructor. By any chance, are you instantiating Template01 in MainWindow? That would do it.

Comment: Great that you added more code, but still you expect people to guess what's inside the `MainWindow` class...

Comment: I do the following: Sprachpaket_ENG_Template01 ENG_01 = new Sprachpaket_ENG_Template01(); --> ENG_01.Template01(); --> do you mean that?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to programming. My application has more than 8000 lines, so I couldn't paste all the code. What do you need to know to find the cause of the error message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your edits and comments, you have this:

```
class Sprachpaket_ENG_Template01
{
    // Create a new MainWindow whenever Sprachpaket_ENG_Template01 is created
    MainWindow MW = new MainWindow();
}

class MainWindow()
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        // Create a new Sprachpaket_ENG_Template01 whenever MainWindow is created
        Sprachpaket_ENG_Template01 ENG_01 = new Sprachpaket_ENG_Template01();
    }
}
```

You have an infinite loop here, which is why you're getting a stack overflow.

You probably wanted to pass MainWindow as a parameter to the Sprachpaket_ENG_Template01 constructor:

```
class Sprachpaket_ENG_Template01
{
    MainWindow MW;

    public Sprachpaket_ENG_Template01(MainWindow mw)
    {
        MW = mw;
    }
}

class MainWindow()
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        Sprachpaket_ENG_Template01 ENG_01 = new Sprachpaket_ENG_Template01(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay thank you very much, I think I've got it! I'm trying to do that --> Response in a few minutes. ;)

Comment: It seems to work, thank you very much! ;)
But how do I "run" the content of the classes in my MainWindow?

Comment: @Exception I don't understand your question. What are you trying to run? You might want to post a separate question...

Comment: Okay I will do this. Thank you.

Comment: NEW TOPIC: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21392981/how-to-run-content-of-a-class